# How do you ship/enable a separate service in android?

Tags: android, service, notifications, backgroundworker

Is it possible to launch a service whenever a phone is booted up?
My question is that, say, I want to have a background service running in the background when the phone is booted up, once it receives a notification, say, a stock price is now above a certain price, then the user will get notified and in the notification center it will launch the actual app if a user chooses to click on it.

My question is, where do I put the  tag? In my application manifest? but again, I only want the service to run automatically without user launching my app.

Comment: Yes, see here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784441/trying-to-start-a-service-on-boot-on-android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see here two possibilities for you:

1. Is the same approach that was proposed by @triad. You can have a broadcast receiver that will start your service.
2. You can use push notifications. As I understand from the question it is possible in your case. I guess using push notifications will be cheaper (in the context of power) in your case.